# How many Isomorphisms are there from $\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_5$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How many Isomorphisms are there from $\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_5$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$

We have generator of $\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ is $1$ and there $\phi(15)=8$ generators of $\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_5$ namely $ (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4)$ and thus there should be $8$ automorphisms.

Answer given at the end is $4$.

Comment: This question is the same as asking "how many automorphisms does $\Bbb{Z}_{15}$ have?". The correct answer is $8$.

Comment: So there must be a typo in the book.